# Configuring php desktop chrome for allowing it to connect to oracle 12c

Tags: php, oracle, phpdesktop

I tried to find folder with PHP INI and i cant find an extension with (php_oci8_12c) However when i tried to check the folder inside PHP desktop app i found that it has php_oci8_12c.dll,  And i tried to insert extension=php_oci8_12c in PHP INI but didn't work. is it possible that i can connect oracle database thru phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3?

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how PHP Desktop works but php_oci8_12c.dll is not a standalone library. It also requires an Oracle client library available, such as Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: what is the best i can do sir? my data is from oracle iam usung a million of data that;s why i cant covert it to sql. is there any way to configure it?

Comment: but in xampp it works perfectly sir. also using oracle database. thanks

Comment: If you already have a working OCI8 set-up for another PHP interpreter I suggest you edit the details into the question since that's quite relevant. I can't provide you with information regarding PHP Desktop because it's a piece of software I'm not familiar with.